# Determine if fitted line is actually one line

Tags: probability, optimization, soft-question, algorithms

I am trying to fit multiple lines through many data points in 3d space. My working method is sequential RANSAC, which now is fast enough and fits some lines, but produces some lines that don't fit one line, but go through multiple true lines, and have enough inliers to be supported.

I then searched for a better algorithm and found J- and T-Linkage (http://www.diegm.uniud.it/fusiello/demo/jlk/), which deal with multiple structures in the dataset natively and should be less dependent on choice of a threshold, but there I get the same problem.

Here's a sample image of the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJqkV.png
It's rather convoluted, but I think you can see the good and problematic lines.

Now I'm looking for a method to robustly reject the bad fits. The true lines all have a roughly similar direction, but apparently not same enough to use as a criterion (though I use the angle to reject samples that are definitively wrong at hypothesis generation).
Another difficulty is that the data is noisy and often, 'true' lines will have missing parts, so rejecting fits if there are 'holes' between points doesn't work.

The authors of the T-Linkage paper suggested a check based on the sample's randomness, but my statistics knowledge is too bad, so I would be glad for pointers if that is a viable idea.

Thanks in advance!